# Transform and PIVOT Microsoft Access - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, pivot, transform

I am trying to convert an Microsoft Access query into SQL Server.

In Access, the SQL is...

```
  TRANSFORM Count(Time_Difference.sc) AS CountOfsc
  SELECT Time_Difference.sc
  FROM Time_Difference
  WHERE (((Time_Difference.Week)>=44 And (Time_Difference.Week)<=48))
  GROUP BY Time_Difference.sc
  PIVOT Time_Difference.spc;
```

I tried to convert to SQL...

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT (Time_Difference.sc AS CountOfsc,
Time_Difference.sc,spc
FROM Time_Difference
WHERE (((Time_Difference.Week)>=44 And (Time_Difference.Week)<=48))
GROUP BY Time_Difference.sc
)T
PIVOT
(
COUNT(CountOfsc)
FOR Time_Difference.spc IN (A,B,C,D,E)
)P
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any example data, I would guess you are looking for something like this:

```
select [O1_supplier],A,B,C,D,E
from (
  select 
    [O1_supplier]
  , spc
  , sc
  from Time_Difference
  where Time_Difference.Week>=44 
    and Time_Difference.Week<=48
  ) as T
pivot (count(sc) for Time_Difference.spc in (A,B,C,D,E))P
```

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo when pasting my code. The issue is I keep getting the error "invalid column name" in my "FOR"

Comment: @tlech provide some sample data and an example of the desired results and that will make things much simpler.